Each zero of an analytic function is isolated proof explanation.
I'm reading "Functions of One Complex Variable - John B. Conway". I have the following corollary (3.9, chapter 4) (my doubt does not rely on something about the main theorem so I am not writing it):

If $f$ is an analytic function on an open connected set $G$ and $f$ is not identically zero then for each $a\in G$ there is an integer $n\geq 1$ and an analytic function $g:G\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(a)\neq 0$ and $f(z)=(z-a)^ng(z)$ for all $z\in $G$. That is, each zero of $f$ has finite multiplicity.

The proof starts like this. Let $n$ be the largest integer $(\geq 1)$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(a)=0$.
I understand you can pick the smallest integer $n$ such that it is not zero, but how can you pick the largest one? if you pick $N$, how do you know there is no $N'>N$ such that the corresponding $(N'-1)$-th derivative is zero?

Hint: what does $f$ being analytic buy you?

it's a bit of notation abuse - what Conway means is that if $f(a)=0$ then also possibly $f'(a)=0$ etc but there is an $n$ where this stops, so, in other words, $f(a)= \cdots =f^{(n-1)}(a)=0$ but $f^{(n)}(a) \ne 0$

Actually, what Conway wrote was

Let $n$ be the largest integer ($\geqslant1$) such that $f^{(k)}(a)=0$ for $0\leqslant k<n$.

If no such largest integer existed, then we would have $f^{(m)}(a)=0$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$ and therefore $f$ would be constant. And, since $n$ is the largest integer such that $f^{(k)}(a)=0$ for $0\leqslant k<n$, $f^{(n)}(a)\ne0$.
